# how to count number of rows in a file in dataflow in a efficient way?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I want to count total number of rows in a file. 
Please explain your code if possible.

String fileAbsolutePath = "gs://sourav_bucket_dataflow/" + fileName;

```
    PCollection<String> data = p.apply("Reading Data From File", TextIO.read().from(fileAbsolutePath));

    PCollection<Long> count = data.apply(Count.<String>globally());
```

Now i want to get the value.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of sinks that you can use to get data out of your pipeline.  https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/ has a list of the current built in IO transforms.

Answer (score 1):

It sort of depends on what you want to do with that number. Assuming you want to use it in your future transformations, you may want to convert it to a PCollectionView object and pass it as a side input to other transformations.

```
    PCollection<String> data = p.apply("Reading Data From File", TextIO.read().from(fileAbsolutePath));
    PCollection<Long> count = data.apply(Count.<String>globally());    

    final PCollectionView<Long> view = count.apply(View.asSingleton());
```

A quick example to show you how to use the value as a side count:

```
    data.apply(ParDo.of(new FuncFn(view)).withSideInputs(view));
```

Where:

```
    class FuncFn extends DoFn<String,String>
    {
      private final PCollectionView<Long> mySideInput;

      public FuncFn(PCollectionView<Long> mySideInput) {
          this.mySideInput = mySideInput;
      }

      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws IOException
      {        
        Long count = c.sideInput(mySideInput);
        //other stuff you may want to do
      }
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

where "input" in line 1 is the input. This will work.

```
PCollection<Long> number = input.apply(Count.globally());
    number.apply(MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<Long, Long>() 
    {
        public Long apply(Long total) 
        {
            System.out.println("Length is: " + total);
            return total;
        }
    }));
```